# scontrol all jobs in user account

Tags: slurm

I am trying to hold all jobs submitted from my account. However, `scontrol hold` only takes in array and I have many arrays. Is there an alternative command like `scancel -u user`?

Edit1:
If iterating all job id is the only way, this is my method:

```
squeue -u user | awk '{print $1;}' | while read jobid; do scontrol hold $jobid; done
```

Comment: Loop over your jobs and hold them one after the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While piping formatted text to `sh` is clever, I would probably do something like this:

```
squeue -u <user> --format "%i" --noheader | xargs scontrol hold
```

or

```
sacct --allocation --user=<user> --noheader --format=jobid | xargs scontrol hold
```

If you wanted to filter by state, you could do that as well:

```
squeue -u <user> --format "%i" --noheader --states=PENDING | xargs scontrol hold
```

or

```
sacct --allocation --user=<user> --noheader --format=jobid --state=PENDING | xargs scontrol hold
```

source: Slurm man pages

Answer (score 2):

A often-used method is to (ab)use the formatting possibilities of `squeue` to build the `scontrol` line:

```
squeue -h -u user --format "scontrol hold job %i"
```

and then pipe that into a shell:

```
squeue -h -u user --format "scontrol hold job %i" | sh
```

Comment: This returns `scontrol hold job JOBID` is it normal?

Comment: That is the header of the `JOBID` column. Suppress it with `-h`. If nothing else is written (assuming no redirection to `sh`), it means `user` has no active job in the system.